# iterating over list of lists, one list at a time

Tags: python, python-3.7

i have a function "sas" which takes 12 arguments.
i created a list with itertools product  like this

```
p = Pool(processes=8)
nar = []
for i, t in itertools.product(range(50, 450, 50), range(50, 450, 50)):
    nar.append([300, 382, i, t, 86, 264, 418, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4])
```

this created a list of lists

i am trying to map a function over this list but it takes only 1 argument at a time , with error "missing 11 required positional arguments: "

i tried 
this

```
data = p.map(sas, nar)
```

and  this

```
data = p.map(sas, [i for i in nar])
```

and some others i suspect even more stupid

how can i iterate over list of lists using list of 12 numbers at a time

Comment: Seems you're looking for `Pool().starmap(yourfunc, nar)`.

Comment: this did work. great.  can i accept a comment as answer?

Comment: ok, . i am new to python as you can probably see. i searched and saw that page amongst others . i could not fix with that. it seems the solution is to use starmap.. thanks , you  were great help whether you like it or not .

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```py
data = [sas(*items) for items in nar]
```

Comment: i have to map calculations on processors, so i cannot escape from "p.map "

Comment: Does this work? `p.map(lambda items: sas(*items), nar)`

Comment: did not work, "pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x00000212584A0438>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed"

Comment: Sorry if it sounds silly, but can `sas` be modified to take a list as argument instead of taking 12 arguments? Your original logic will then work. Alteratively, write the lambda as a normal function and supply p.map with the name of the function.